# Jenkins Build Failure

Tags: java, maven, build, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm getting a failure on my Jenkins build and I'm struggling to work out why. Perhaps I'm being blind, but I can't see Jenkins reporting any exceptions, errors or permissions problems in it's console output.

The build commands are "clean site install -Dmaven.test.skip=true" and I can confirm that when I use these locally with the mvn command, the build works fine.

What am I missing here?

[Jenkins Build Log](http://pastebin.com/cL3X029K)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have  you tried to run a shell script with your build with your maven command build ?

For unknown reason, I had this issue after exporting a job to a new jenkins and didn't figure out.
I run a shell script with the same command as the jenkins build performs and everything works fine.

This answers is only a workaround as I didn't get the proper reason too...

If you launch your command with **-X** argument, you'll also have more information on your issue.